# How do I exclude bias from regularization using TensorFlow's `matrix_solve_ls`?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, regularized

Given a [design matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_matrix) (with an initial column of 1s corresponding to a bias factor), I can perform standard NN-style L2-Regularized parameter estimation, in which [*only the weights* are regularized](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/153605/16694), with a variety of Python tools such as

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(lambda p: np.mean((np.dot(dmat, p) - y_data)**2) + lamb*np.dot(p[1:], p[1:]), np.zeros(n_params).T).x
```

or

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(lambda p: np.mean((np.dot(dmat, p) - y_data)**2) + 2*lamb*tf.nn.l2_loss(p[1:]).eval(), np.zeros(n_params).T).x
```

But I see no way to exclude the bias from regularization with TensorFlow's [`tf.matrix_solve_ls`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matrix_solve_ls) which treats

```
tf.matrix_solve_ls(dmat, np.array([y_data]).T, l2_regularizer=lamb*len(dmat)).eval()
```

as equivalent to

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(lambda p: np.mean((np.dot(dmat, p) - y_data)**2) + lamb*np.dot(p, p), np.zeros(n_params).T).x
```

How do I exclude bias (or, by construction, the first parameter) from regularization using `tf.matrix_solve_ls`?

Comment: Not sure about using `tf.matrix_solve_ls`, but I have done this before by only calculating my regularization term on those variables that do not contain the word "bias". Something like `reg_term = tf.norm([var for var in tf.trainable_variables() if not 'bias' in var.name])` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with the current version of matrix_solve_ls. On the other hand, the default (fast) path in matrix_solve_ls was recently changed to simply be a composite Python function:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/linalg_ops.py#L293

You can easily make a version of this code where the l2_regularizer is a vector (with a separate value for each parameter). It would probably be a good idea to implement such a generalization in matrix_solve_ls in general. Perhaps you can submit this change as a pull request?